# Node JS - Asynchronous Function Returning undefined

Tags: node.js

I am trying to check whether user document is present on our database or not and he/she is already verified or not and at last i want to return the user document from that function . but i am unable to catch the returned user document into another function . all i get is undefined .

Function Returning User Document

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const AppError = require('./AppError');
const catchAsync = require('./catchAsync');
const sendEmailVerificationToken = require('../utility/sendEmailVerification');

function generateToken() {
    const token = crypto.randomBytes(120).toString('hex');
    return token;
}

exports.createConfimationLinkAndSendEmail = (document) => {
    const token = generateToken();
    const confirmationLink = `localhost:3000/api/v1/verify/${token}`;
    sendEmailVerificationToken(
        confirmationLink,
        (document.email = 'Rohan@gmail.com')
    );
    return token;
};

exports.doUserExistAndNotVerified = catchAsync(async (userId, model, next) => {
    if (!userId) return next(new AppError('Please Enter USER ID'));
    const userDocument = await model.findById(userId);
    if (!userDocument) return next(new AppError('User Doesnot Exist'));
    if (userDocument.isVerified)
        return next(new AppError('Email is Already Verified'));

    return userDocument;
});
```

Catching returning value from the doUserExistAndNotVerified Function

```
 exports.confirmEmail = catchAsync(async (request, response, next) => {
    const { userId } = request.body;

    //CHECKING IF USER EXIST AND EMAIL IS  VERIFIED OR NOT
    const userDocument = await emailHandler.doUserExistAndNotVerified(
        userId,
        User,
        next
    );


    // FINDING TOKEN DOCUMENT BY HASH TOKEN AND USERID
    const hashedToken = crypto
        .createHash('sha256')
        .update(request.params.verificationToken)
        .digest('hex');

    const tokenDocument = await emailVerificationModel.findOne({
        owner: userId,
        token: hashedToken,
    });

    // CHECKING IF TOKEN DOCUMENT IS EMPTY
    if (!tokenDocument) return next(new AppError('Link Has Expired'));
    userDocument.isVerified = true;

    // CHANGING TOKEN AND USER DOCUMENT
    await userDocument.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });
    await emailVerificationModel.deleteOne({ owner: userDocument._id });

    // SENDING RESPONSE
    response.status(200).json({
        message: 'Email Verified Successfully',
    });
});
```

if i console userDocument it is undefined

Comment: What is `catchAsync`? What is `next` and what does it return?

Comment: Could you post the complete code of the function where you call `emailHandler.doUserExistAndNotVerified()`, please?

Comment: i have posted my full code you can check out .

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @JRichardsz According to the comment on my answer, they have

Answer (score 0):

You should not put `catchAsync` around everything, but only around your http middlewares/handlers that actually send a response or call `next`, but do not `return` a value.

Make `doUserExistAndNotVerified` a normal async function that returns a promise for the user:

```
exports.doUserExistAndNotVerified = async (userId, model) => {
    if (!userId) throw new AppError('Please Enter USER ID');
    const userDocument = await model.findById(userId);
    if (!userDocument) throw new AppError('User Doesnot Exist');
    if (userDocument.isVerified) throw new AppError('Email is Already Verified');
    return userDocument;
};
```

By throwing exceptions (rejecting the returned promise) you actually cause the abnormal control flow and make the `catchAsync` of `confirmEmail` handle the `AppError`, previously your function just called `next()` directly and then still did return `undefined` normally even when there was an error.